# Excel AutoFill Reference other sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want a column to contain multiples of 9 in reference to cells on the first page (that I've titled Log). So column will be =Log!F9 then =Log!F18, etc. Is there a way to make this Autofill work? If I just have F9, and F18, select and autofill, it will do the multiples of 9, but not if I have the reference to "Log"

Answer (score 1):

You can use an Index formula where the second argument is created by a formula, for example

```
=INDEX(log!F:F,ROW(A1)*9)
```

Copy down.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the formulas on the second sheet to actually be `=Log!F9,` `=Log!F18`..., you can do the following:

1. Enter the formula `="=Log!F"&ROW(A1)*9` in the second sheet and copy it down.
2. Select the formulas and copy and paste them in place as values.
3. Select them again and do a find and replace all, with the `=` sign set as both the find value and the replace value.